# MediaPlayer: start called in state 0, mPlayer(0x0)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm developing a simple music player, but an error appeared **sometimes**(just one line error):

> Error: start called in state 0, mPlayer(0x0)

I have a `MusicService` for operating something about music. Part of it:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
    mediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
}
...

public void play(String url) {
    try {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
...

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    mp.start();
    addTimer();
    status = MUSIC_STATUS_PLAYING;
}
```

When I open a **Activity**, and bind **MusicService**, execute `play()`, the error appeared sometimes.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue in **Kotlin**, and I was able to tackle it.

---

In my case I added the MediaPlayer.create() inside a Boolean statement, so let's say in fragment 1 I use a Boolean called "globalAudio", I set this Boolean globally true from "MyModel" class, hence it will execute MediaPlayer.create as normal since it is true outside the conditional body. But, if I move to fragment 2 and set the Boolean "globalAudio" to false and when I go back to fragment 1, the Logcat will throw me error "pause called in state 64, mPlayer(0xca47c070)" and "error (-38, 0)", because I am attempting to start the audio without Media.create() being set up.

---

I attached the problem and the solution below to make the understanding easier for you

---

Problem

```
if (MyModel.StaticData.globalAudio) { // A
    homeAudio = MediaPlayer.create(requireActivity(), R.raw.background1)
    homeAudio.setVolume(MyModel.StaticData.backgroundVolume, MyModel.StaticData.backgroundVolume)         
}
if (homeAudio.isPlaying) { // B
    homeAudio.pause() // pause
    homeAudio.seekTo(0) // set start from 00:00
}

if (!homeAudio.isPlaying) { // C
    homeAudio.start() // throws error if A is not executed
}
```

Solution

```
//A
homeAudio = MediaPlayer.create(requireActivity(), R.raw.background1)
homeAudio.setVolume(MyModel.StaticData.backgroundVolume, MyModel.StaticData.backgroundVolume)

if (homeAudio.isPlaying) { // B
    homeAudio.pause() // pause
    homeAudio.seekTo(0) // set start from 00:00
}

if (!homeAudio.isPlaying) { // C
    homeAudio.start() // won't throw error because A is always executed
}
```

---

Here I provide you a Kotlin code that it can be automatically converted to Java in Android Studio:

```
var myAudio = MediaPlayer.create(requireActivity(), R.raw.[yourAudio])
myAudio.setVolume([leftChannelInFLoat], [rightChannelInFLoat])

if (myAudio.isPlaying) {
    myAudio.pause()
    myAudio.seekTo(0)
}

if (!hmyAudio.isPlaying) {
    myAudio.start()
}
```